# Log Parser - Query through MSUtill and Read Record through C# codes

Tags: c#, logparser

i find lot of Threads about Log Parser, but none fulfill my desire,

i need to Apply this query over log parser
select * from security

And get the event rows, then read them row by row, knowing which column i access...

please help...

what should be down:
1.Query Windows Event Through LogParser.dll (Using MSUtill Library) 
2.Get and put the rows inside any container
3.read rows one by one
4.be capable to separate each cell of row, and read them separately like access event id column, or message column ...

---

### --To the question

there were things, but i didng get them, 
for example, the person use this, take single row, but i need multi row, i'm wonder what to convert next :| what class i need to use

```
LogQueryClass logger = new LogQueryClassClass();
            COMIISW3CInputContextClass inputContext = new COMIISW3CInputContextClassClass();
            string query = // i change it during test
            ILogRecord record = logger.Execute(query, inputContext).getRecord();
```

or another use this : it seem that return single result too

```
// prepare LogParser Recordset & Record objects
            ILogRecordset rsLP = null;
            ILogRecord rowLP = null;

            LogQueryClassClass LogParser = null;
            COMW3CInputContextClassClass W3Clog = null;

            double UsedBW = 0;
            int Unitsprocessed;
            double sizeInBytes;

            string strSQL = null;

            LogParser = new LogQueryClassClass();
            W3Clog = new COMW3CInputContextClassClass();

            try
            {
                //W3C Logparsing SQL. Replace this SQL query with whatever 
                //you want to retrieve. The example below 
                //will sum up all the bandwidth
                //Usage of a specific folder with name 
                //"userID". Download Log Parser 2.2 
                //from Microsoft and see sample queries.

                strSQL = //the query (i changed it during test)

                // run the query against W3C log
                rsLP = LogParser.Execute(strSQL, W3Clog);

                rowLP = rsLP.getRecord();

                Unitsprocessed = rsLP.inputUnitsProcessed;

                if (rowLP.getValue(0).ToString() == "0" ||
                    rowLP.getValue(0).ToString() == "")
                {
                    //Return 0 if an err occured
                    UsedBW = 0;
                    return UsedBW;
                }

                //Bytes to MB Conversion
                double Bytes = Convert.ToDouble(rowLP.getValue(0).ToString());
                UsedBW = Bytes / (1024 * 1024);
```

best query i find was this, it search inside registery ( i dont have the orginal query since i changed it

```
ILogRecordset rs = null;
            try
            {
                LogQueryClass qry = new LogQueryClass();
                COMRegistryInputContextClass registryFormat = new COMRegistryInputContextClass();
                string query = //Chnaged it
                rs = qry.Execute(query, registryFormat);
                for (; !rs.atEnd(); rs.moveNext())
                    Console.WriteLine(rs.getRecord().toNativeString(","));
            }
            finally
            {
                rs.close();
            }
```

also there are things, which seem to return data to SQL not as live object :|

### since i gonna write service, i want to have minimum possible access to data base for exchange data, just store current data

### --Edit:

let me add, my query (using passing "log parser.exe" argument) was like this, but it's so rude for me to call a exe file, inside of a service.

```
myProc.StartInfo.Arguments = " \"select * INTO AuditLogParser from \\\\" + Dns.GetHostName() +
                                         "\\security WHERE TimeGenerated >= '" + startDate +
                                         "' and TimeGenerated <'" + endDate +
                                         "' and (eventid=560 or eventid=540)\" -o:SQL -server:\"" +
                                         Dns.GetHostName() +
                                         "\\sqlexpress\"  -database:SecurityLog -driver:\"SQL Server\" -username:TrainAudit -password:Password.110 -createtable:OFF";
```

Comment: comment doesnt have capacity ,and it dont allow me post answer for 8 hour :|

Comment: i perform edit, check main post

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following sample code uses LogParser to read the file name and size from a local directory named `C:\Bat`

```
LogQueryClass logQuery = new LogQueryClassClass();

COMFileSystemInputContextClass inputFormat = new COMFileSystemInputContextClassClass();
inputFormat.recurse = 0;

String strQuery = @"SELECT Name, Size FROM 'C:\Bat\*.*' ORDER BY Name ASC";

ILogRecordset results = logQuery.Execute(strQuery, inputFormat);
while (! results.atEnd())
{
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("File: {0} Size: {1}", results.getRecord().getValue("Name"), results.getRecord().getValue(1)));
    results.moveNext();
}
```

Note that I can access the column by the name of the column from the query or by the column index.

Comment: BTW, dont you think it's rude to parse into a file :| what i want is not store data into a file, i want something like my third example, the one start with this line:
 
 ILogRecordset rs = null;

but as your example, with indexed output, or class instance output...

Comment: Huh?  This does not parse into a file. The above code gets a recordset and loops over it.  What else do you want?

Comment: aha, sry, it read from a file :D wow, BTW, this log parser thing is very powerful, i see user use it everywhere :-s

Comment: man, BTW, that's COMFileSystemInputContextClass, i want to query through system event tables, which is in securiry, now what class i should use?
my query through logparser2.2.exe as a argument was :
" \"select * INTO AuditLogParser from \\\\" + Dns.GetHostName() +"\\security WHERE TimeGenerated >= '" + startDate +"' and TimeGenerated <'" + endDate +"' and (eventid=560 or eventid=540)\" -o:SQL -server:\"" +Dns.GetHostName() +"\\sqlexpress\"  -database:SecurityLog -driver:\"SQL Server\" -username:TrainAudit -password:Password.110 -createtable:OFF"

Comment: I'm going to guess `COMEventLogInputContextClass` and `COMSYSLOGOutputContextClass` respectively.

Comment: they all return key value pair? like the previous sample? i mean i can access them just by index-ed string or index number right?
BTW tnx, for your truble...
i find new issue, which os dont let me access Windows security log, with \\<DNS Host Name>\Security
so, i have to fix it before i continue